# yii 2.0 on ajax submit error Class 'app\controllers\ActiveForm' not found

Tags: php, ajax, yii, active-form

I have the following error

> Class 'app\controllers\ActiveForm' not found

when submit the following `ActiveForm` (kartik\widgets\ActiveForm)

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'type'=>ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL,
    'action' => 'incarico/update/'.$model->id,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
]);
```

My controller has this action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

}
```

The error refers to this line

```
return ActiveForm::validate($model);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't include `ActiveForm` namespace yet.

add this in the `use` section (in the beginning of that file)

`use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;`

Comment: Try to use IDE like NetBeans or PHPStorm will make ur life much easier when working with framework.

Comment: I've just downloaded netbeans to give it a try. Thank you